# Tracker never-endingly indexes cloud storage, never remembers what it's learned

Tags: cloud, tracker, pcloud

tracker-store lately runs at 100% of CPU on my computer.  I know there are questions addressing ways to shut it down entirely, but I don't want to do this.

I have a guess what is happening. This computer, running Ubuntu 20.04, also has a folder that mirrors a folder on a cloud server (pCloud). This service opens on startup, but does have to be logged into each time. I believe that what tracker is doing is reindexing the cloud drive every time, and forgetting that data every time it suspends. The search tool (Windows button, on this machine) is also sometimes unusably slow, and I hypothesize that this is related.

**How could I verify what tracker is doing and, if my guess is right, get tracker to maintain the data so I can do searches reliably?**